`PAGE.png' not found on input line 10
I am trying generate Quran pdf. but having following issue:
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] (./pages.tex

LaTeX Warning: File `PAGE.png' not found on input line 10.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `PAGE.png' not found: using draft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 ...degraphics[width=0.87\textwidth]{PAGE.png}
                                                  
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 ...degraphics[width=0.87\textwidth]{PAGE.png}
                                                  
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on quran.log.

here is the page.tex:
\hspace{-2em}
Page \thepage \hfill Part PART
\vspace{-2.5em}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.87\textwidth]{PAGE.png}
\end{figure}
\newpage


and here is the genpage.tex.sh:
!/bin/bash

partfrom=${PART_FROM:-1}
partto=${PART_TO:-30}

if [ $partfrom -eq 1 ]; then
  page=0
else
  page=$[(partfrom-1)*20+1]
fi

function pageout() {
  pg=$1
  pt=$2
  cat page.tex | sed "s/PAGE/$pg/" | sed "s/PART/$pt/"
}

function partout() {
  pt=$1
  cat partheader.tex | sed "s/PART/$pt/"
}

echo "\\setcounter{page}{$[page+1]}"

for part in `seq $partfrom $partto`; do
  partout $part
  [ $part -eq 1 ] && pageout 1 $part && page=1

   gen 20 pages
  for i in `seq 1 20`; do
    pageout $[page+i] $part
  done

  page=$[page+20]
done

if [ $part -eq 30 ]; then
  -- finally gen 3 pages
  for page in 602 603 604; do
    pageout $page $part
  done
fi

I dont know what is the issue.
Please assist.
Thank you

you have posted some fragments of code but not enough to guess what is wrong, your fragment is clearly part of a latex document but it has no \documentclass or other required commands and it includes PAGE.png which is apparently not available. You do show a fragment of shell script that would replace PAGE by a number, but do you have the png at all?

From the error it seems the shell script didn't run or it didn't perform the substitutions. What is your compile sequence, i.e., at which point do you call the script?
